# Not able to connect ESXi host remotely via a Secure Shell client

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed a CentOS in VMware server and if I open the VMware console then I am able to connect to the server but if I use putty in my desktop then I am not able to connect to the host.

```
1) Started SSH service in the VMware host configuration.
2) Added IP and hostname in the /etc/hosts file
```

Comment: Only other thought would be to ensure the SSH service is indeed running on the host and make sure the firewall rules support your system connecting to the host.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kyle Ruddy. I fixed this issue by allowing certain IP in the Firewall settings. Its working now.